# Qt resource file works on Windows XP but not on Windows 7?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, windows-xp

[image]I made a program in Qt on Windows XP, Now I am porting that code on Windows 7, but when I compile the code, the pictures and icons pic in .qrc (resource file) are not displaying in program. Those pictures are in the same folder where the header file and .cpp files are present.

Thanks

Here is the code:

```
void MainWindow::on_actionUmer_s_Program_triggered()
{
    QMessageBox about;

    about.setFont(QFont("Times",13,0,false));
    about.setText("<h2>Umer's Program</h2>");
    setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/pics/umerfariiq.jpg"));
    about.setInformativeText("Copyright ; 2012 Umer Software Inc.\nI wrote this program for fun I am a student of System engineering at UET Peshawar.\nAll thanks to Almighty for giving me the capability to write it\n");
    about.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Ok);
    about.setIconPixmap(QPixmap(":/pics/umergokuup.jpg"));
    about.setDefaultButton(QMessageBox::Ok);
    about.show();
    about.exec();
}
```

Qmake

QT       += core gui

TARGET = Commentprogram
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    itemdialog.cpp \
    commentdialog.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    itemdialog.h \
    commentdialog.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui \
    itemdialog.ui \
    commentdialog.ui

RESOURCES += \
    pics.qrc

and this is the picture of .qrc file

Comment: Post all of your relevant code please!

Comment: thats a very big code. and contains 4 or file header files and .cpp files

Comment: The most important part is not the code, but the project configuration. Please post the build script (qmake) and the list of all relevant files (some sources, and your image) relative to the build script

Comment: Sorry, forgot to say that the content of the qrc file is also relevant.

Comment: Either the qrc file is not processed (check in the build output to see if rcc is invoked, and try to clean and rebuild), or the qrc is incorrect (we need the __content__ of the qrc, ie **Open with -> Notepad** and paste the content here)

Comment: Try to generate a new qrc file on Windows 7 to see if there are some differences between the new qrc file and the original one.